# How can one get state of the art results on Cifar10 with the All Convolution Net?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I was trying to replicate the results of [Striving for Simplicity: The All Convolutional Net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6806)  but I seem unable to. I've copied all the hyperparams from the implementation provided by [StefOe](https://github.com/StefOe/all-conv-pytorch/blob/master/allconv.py) and I'm not sure what to do. I get ~0.2 error instead of ~0.1. Has anyone been able to replicate this result on Pytorch?

The training looks fine, so I'm not sure what is going wrong:

[image]

---

Other related links:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-net-from-striving-for-simplicity-the-all-convolutional-net/19297/2

---

### **Code**:

https://github.com/StefOe/all-conv-pytorch/blob/master/allconv.py

https://github.com/StefOe/all-conv-pytorch/blob/master/cifar10.ipynb

Comment: You obtained "~0.2 error instead of ~0.1", but you link to a class definition only. What was your batch size? Training epochs? You should include your own code, providing these details, and possibly others (data augmentation?)...

Comment: @desertnaut  its the second link under code section

Comment: Please provide your code.  Besides, you are clearly overfitting.

Comment: @FredGuth is there something wrong with the links I provided? I can copy paste them if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least get 13% error when using SGD with lr 0.01, momentum 0.9 and batch-size 32. I use the data augmentation as given in the implementation. In the paper, also a weight decay of 0.001 is used. For me that lead to 14%.
So the implementation uses a different learning rate and also no whitening and contrast normalization is used. Maybe those last two are the key to get to 7.25%.

Anyway, the results are pretty weird, since without data augmentation the network should already reach 9.08%.